# Determine if F is the curl of another vector field. Find that vector field if it exists.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

I am working on a homework problem that requires me to find the curl of another vector field–which I can easily find if the $\nabla \cdot F=0$. However, I am stuck on the portion that requires me to solve for that vector field, given that the $\nabla \cdot F$ is indeed zero.

In other words, I am being asked to backtrack, and instead of finding the curl between two vectors, I am asked to find that vector field whose curl is given to me.

To be more specific, the vector given (which is indeed the curl of another v.f.) is:

$<-\sin(x), \cos(y), z\cos(x) + z\sin(y)>$.

Given that its divergence is equal to zero, **how do I find the vector field that outputs the given v.f. above; how do I reverse the curl in order to find $F$ in  $\nabla \times F$?** I am not sure whether to integrate each component (as it is the antiderivative).

Is there another formula I can refer to? I am aware that I can simply set the equation up as such:

$<-\sin(x), \cos(y), z\cos(x) + z\sin(y)> \text{ }= \left(\frac{dF3}{dy} - \frac{dF2}{dz}\right)i - \left(\frac{dF3}{dx} - \frac{dF1}{dz}\right)j + \left(\frac{dF2}{dx} - \frac{dF1}{dy}\right)k$

But how do I find the actual, *F1*, *F2*, and *F3* components for the desired vector field? Is integration involved?

Please advise. Thank you in advance for your help.

*if needed, the questions reads, "Which of the following vector fields is the curl of another vector field? Find the vector field if it exists.*

*a) $F = <x\cos(y), z\sin(y), xyz>$

*b) $F = <-\sin(x), \cos(y), z\cos(x) + z\sin(y)>$

and I only need help with letter b).